# Rails 5: How to get the public_profile, user_location, and user_status via FB omniauth on Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth-facebook

I have Rails 5 app using Facebook Omniauth on Devise and I want to pull the user's public_profile info such as `first_name, last_name, age_range, link, gender, locale, verified, user_location, and user_status` into my `Users` table. Right now, it only gets email when using the default Devise setup:-

```
# user.rb
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
  user.email = auth.info.email
  user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
  user.username = auth.info.name
  user.photo = auth.info.image
  user.skip_confirmation!
  user.save

# devise.rb
config.omniauth :facebook, '..', '..', image_size: 'large'
```

I tried to edit those files to get the details, but it doesn't work:-

```
# devise.rb
config.omniauth :facebook, '..', '..', image_size: 'large', scope: 'email, public_profile, user_location, user_status', info_fields: 'first_name, last_name, gender, age_range, etc.'

# user.rb
  user.first_name = auth.extra.raw_info.first_name
  user.last_name = auth.extra.raw_info.last_name
  user.age_range = auth.extra.raw_info.age_range
  user.gender = auth.extra.raw_info.gender
  user.address = auth.info.user_location
  user.status = auth.info.user_status
```

I don't know how to write the above properly to get them to work. I have permission to get `user_location` and `user_status`

Comment: What was the solution?

Comment: I wasn't able to get it to work so I changed the requirement